# Raikov's thm: Given two rv X,Y with $X+Y=Z\sim Poisson(\lambda)$, then X,Y is Poisson

Tags: pr.probability

Can smn give a reference for Raikov's theorem? The only one I found is in Russian.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raikov%27s_theorem

or give the proof

I am trying to do it with characteristics

Comment: What's wrong with the two English references given in the Wikipedia article you cited?

Comment: I remember Oleszkiewicz assigned this as a homework problem but no one solved it ;)

Answer (score 5):

Yes,

[Lukacs, E., Characteristic functions, Griffin, 1960, p. 242.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5188175/%5BEugene_Lukacs%5DRaikov.pdf)